# What are the best practices for SharePoint server 2013 at VM hardware level?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, integrate-remedy-sp2013

What are the best practices for SharePoint server 2013 at VM hardware level?

Comment: best practices in which prospective !  Installation, Management, Administrations !

Answer (score 1):

basically it depends about the one's requirement. How many users you are expecting, what service application will be used, purpose of the farm etc.
here are some hardware requirement:

```
Type                                           Memory        Processor   
Dev/stage/test server                          8GB RAM        4 CPU

All-in-one Database/Web/Service Application    24GB RAM       4 CPU

Web/SA server                                  12GB RAM       4 CPU
DB server (medium environments)                16GB RAM       8 CPU

DB server (small environments)                 8GB RAM        4 CPU
```

Here is really good article from Technet, which will cover all topics in it.

[Use best practice configurations for the SharePoint 2013 virtual machines and Hyper-V environment](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621103.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#RevBP)